# Electrum 2.x sweep feature

Tags: electrum, private-key-import

Could some explain how Electrum sweep feature works?

As I understand "sweep" can be used only after importing private key into wallet. But private key can't be imported into *deterministic* Electrum 2.x wallet.

So why it shows me sweep option?

It there any ways to sweep paper wallet into *deterministic* Electrum wallet?

Answer (score 2):

The sweep function will send all coins related to the imported private key(s) to a new address (from the deterministic wallet). After sweeping, the private key is no longer capable of spending coins.

There is no need to "import" the private key in advance.

Mind that you need to pay a fee for the sweeping transaction (which is very little).

Comment: OK, I have a private key from a paper wallet, click on "sweep", enter it, select one of my receiving address, press "OK" and nothing happens. There is no any confirmation or an error messages. Nothing.

Comment: Sweeping and importing private keys are different mechanisms for topping off your wallet. Sweeps require an extra transaction on a Blockchain.  Miners also practice having pools sweep their earnings into a addresses associated with cold wallets.