# How can I move BTC wallet and funds from Block.io?

Tags: wallet, block.io

Unfortunately I can't access dashboard on block.io for some unknown reason. I get the following message from block.io

> We're sorry, but something went wrong. If you are the application owner check the logs for more information.

I have private keys from block.io. I want to transfer the funds in block.io to another address.

Comment: you have tried to contact a support block.io?

Comment: yes no replay unfortinately.

Answer (score 3):

That error message suggests that there may be a short term problem inside the systems operated by Bitcoin.io, in which case I would just retry every day or so.

Clause 5.1.2 of their user agreement says

> When you create a Wallet, the Wallet software generates a cryptographic private and public key pair that you may use to send and receive any supported Virtual Currency via the relevant Virtual Currency network. You are solely responsible for storing, outside of the Services, a backup of any Wallet, private key or transaction information that you maintain in your Wallet or otherwise with the Services. If you do not maintain a backup of your Wallet data outside of the Services, you will be may not be able to access Virtual Currency previously accessed using your Wallet in the event that we discontinue or no longer offer some or all of the Services or may otherwise lose access to Virtual Currency. We are not responsible for maintaining this data on your behalf.

If you have the [private keys in a known format](https://en.bitcoin.it/wiki/Private_key), you should be able to import them or sweep them into a [normal Bitcoin wallet](https://bitcoin.org/en/choose-your-wallet)

- [How do I import a private key into Bitcoin-Core?](https://bitcoin.stackexchange.com/questions/5941/how-do-i-import-a-private-key-into-bitcoin-core)
- [Electrum 2.x sweep feature](https://bitcoin.stackexchange.com/q/37906/13866)

etc.

Please read about the advantages and disadvantages of importing vs sweeping and differences between full-node and SPV wallets.

Comment: thanks for taking the time to replay, i get the following message after executing importprivkey: 
16:01:37
￼
Executing command using "" wallet


16:01:37
￼
importprivkey(…)


16:02:25
￼
null

Comment: @H3LLB0Y: That seems normal. Remember that Bitcoin-core needs to download and scan the entire blockchain - which can take a long time (days, weeks depending on your hardware and speed of Internet connection)

Comment: isn't there a faster way to transfer the funds other than bitcoin core! its just 2 slow and needs 2 days to complete synchronization.

Comment: @H3LLB0Y: There are [SPV](https://bitcoin.org/en/glossary/simplified-payment-verification) wallets such as [Electrum](https://electrum.org/#home). Please make sure you understand the implications of *importing* compared to *sweeping*.

Comment: just as i suspected, now bitcoin core has finished but balance is still 0 whats next?

Comment: I would check that block.io uses the same HD derivation paths as Bitcoin-core. Some wallets allow you to specify the derivation path.

Answer (score 0):

Watch my video on how to extract coins from block[dot]io without using block[dot]io at https://youtu.be/jw0l2Dwmi6g